# Connect Gerrit to Jira always return 401

Tags: jira, gerrit, jira-rest-api

Currently, our team using Jira at [https://XXXX.atlassian.net].
I have set up a private Git server with Gerrit review (3.0.3) on it and installed the its-jira plugin to connect to Jira, however it always return 401 error whenever I try to test the connection.

What did I do wrong here? I have read the configuration document at [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/its-jira/+show/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md)

its-jira plugin in: https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/job/plugin-its-jira-bazel-stable-3.0/
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 means unauthorized, so Gerrit is not accepting your JIRA username and password for some reason. Try

```
curl -v -u tmtuan@:$PASSWORD https://XXXX.atlassian.net
```

I'd expect that to fail with 401 as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
Although my username/password are not wrong. They are affected due to this article:  

https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/blog/2018/06/say-goodbye-to-usernames-in-atlassian-cloud  

Therefore, I have to access to https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens, create token and provided it as "password".  

After that I can curl the site correctly.

Comment: Thanks for adding the solution, I edited my answer.